# The notation $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for the space of twisted one-forms?

Tags: reference-request, notation, mathematical-physics, tensors

I recently came across the notation $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. I believe this is a notation for the vector space of what some authors, such as William L. Burke, call twisted one-forms. That is, they behave like vectors under an orientation-preserving change of coordinates, but their direction has an external "screw-sense" rather than an internal orientation. I believe Burke's description is in the spirit of an older one by Schouten, but Burke's notation and coordinate-free approach are totally different.

Since I don't think Schouten or Burke's notation and terminology are widely understood by mathematicians, I would like to understand the system of notation to which the $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ belongs. Can anyone tell me if I'm understanding it correctly, tell me what words correspond to the notation, and relate it to a broader system of notation, possibly referring to some published source? Unfortunately I came across this only in one of those peep-hole views of a book in google, and I failed to write down the name of the book. It's possible that I'm mistaken in my memory or understanding of the notation.

Comment: this notation looks like exterior square of the vector space $\textbf{R}^3$.

Comment: What you're looking at is commonly referred to as an [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).  $\wedge$ is called an "alternating" or "exterior" tensor product.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: No, $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is just a vector space and not an algebra. The exterior algebra of $\mathbb R^3$ is $\Lambda(\mathbb R^3)=\oplus_{i=0}^3 \Lambda^i(\mathbb R^3)$, which is a graded algebra of dimension $8$ of which the $3$-dimensional vector space $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the graded component of degree $2$. This is very well explained in [the following section of your own link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Exterior_power) and in [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Graded_structure)

Comment: Ben, be warned that a few textbooks use the symbol $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to denote the dual of the correct vector space, namely they use the symbol under discussion to denote alternating $2$-forms, which actually should be denoted $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$. Or even worse: they write  $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ when they really mean differential 2-forms,  which are smooth maps $\mathbb R^3\to \Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$.  Lang's *Undergraduate Analysis* (Chapter XXI) is an excellent reference on both the algebraic and advanced calculus aspects the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\wedge^2(\Bbb R^3)$ is the second [exterior power of $\Bbb R^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Exterior_power). Hopefully that page proves useful.